# how can i do check login is success then only click on menus in Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am new in selenium c#, I am trying to click on menus after login and if already i logged in then its directly go to click on menus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCwyn.png)

```
 [Test, Order(01)]
    public void Req_Search()
    {
        Config config = new Config();
        Menus menu = new Menus();
        Login_methods login = new Login_methods();
        if (loginpage.Logged_status == "logged")
        {
            string current_Url = Driver.driver.Url;
            if (!current_Url.Contains("candidate/candidate-add"))
                menu.Navigate_Applicant_add();
        }
        else
        {
            login.Initilize_Driver();
            loginpage.Valid_login();
            menu.Navigate_Applicant_add();
        }

        //
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the title of the page, in else condition

```
String expectedtitle = "type expected title";

String actualtitle = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("copy xpath perticuler title")).Text.ToString();

Assert.AreEqual(expectedtitle, actualtitle)
```